# Notepad++ Replace all lines starting with

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Here is the original line:

```
Ore(DIAMOND_ORE,7,1,100.0,0,16,STONE)
```

I have 320 files containing that but with other params, I just want to search for:

```
Ore(DIAMOND_ORE
```

And replace the whole line by:

```
Ore(DIAMOND_ORE,1,1,1,0,5,STONE)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The search regex you want is `^Ore\(DIAMOND_ORE.*`

The `^` character means match the beginning of a line and the `.*` means match any character any number of times.

For a single file you can use the simple search and replace feature.

Make sure the find and replace box has *Regular Expressions* checked and that *. matches newline* is **not** checked.

Then set your replacement text to

`Ore\(DIAMOND_ORE,1,1,1,0,5,STONE\)`

Your search and replace box should look like this:

[image]

Hit *Replace All*.  Done.

> I have 320 files containing that but with other params

If you have multiple files to process, just click on the *Find in Files* tab and set your filter and directory, and then hit *Replace in Files*.  I recommend you back-up your target files first though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set search mode "Regular expression"
Find what: ^Ore\(DIAMOND_ORE.*
Replace with: Ore\(DIAMOND_ORE,1,1,1,0,5,STONE\)
```